# How to use lower bound to condition distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Say that I know that the height of a population comes from a distribution $P_H$.

I now pick a random individual. However, someone tells me that he is taller than $H_m$. What is the new distribution of his height? Do I merely truncate $P_H$?

Comment: You have to renormalise the distribution, so if $p(h)$ is the pdf of $P_H$ the pdf of the distribution given $h>h_m$ is $p(h)/[\int_{h_m}^{\infty}p(h)dh]$ for $h>h_m$ and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  by definition truncated r.v is just a conditioned r.v. that was scaled up appropriately, i.e., let $X\sim P_H$, so
$$
P(X=x|X>H_m) = \frac{P(X=x \cap X>H_m)}{P(X>H_m)}.
$$
But the more interesting question is whether you can "merely" truncate. For instance, if your $P_H$ is exponential r.v with $\lambda$ then it is straightforward to show that $ P(X=x|X>H_m) = \lambda e^{-x(\lambda-H_m)} $ or geometric r.v with $p$, hence $ P(X=x|X>H_m) = (1-p)^{x-H_m}p $. So the conditioned distribution which is the truncated one, simply equals to a shifted r.v by $H_m$ . However, as far as I know, from the distributions that belong to the exponential family class, those two are the only cases that satisfy this property. Otherwise, this normalization can be none trivial. So the truncated r.v may or may not (depends on $P_H$) have a close analytical form that you can work with.

Comment: I see. You point out an even more interesting subject in your answer. My intuition did not like the idea of truncation exactly because is seems very very messy for certain distributions.